Wireless charging disturbing PCB (USB-PD shut-down)
I'm using an ESP32 and the STUSB4500 for USB-C PD power negotation. I can set the output voltage VCC to either 5V or 12V and depending on my need.
When I hook up a wireless charging device (product link below) at 12V, the system shuts down and the STUSB4500 does no longer want to operate.. Interestingly it works at reduced VCC voltage of 5V -> hence, the charging is super slow!
I'm not that much experienced with electronic circuitry but my guess will be that there are sudden surges, peaks that disturb the PCB. Is there anyone out there to advice on this matter? Any common solutions how to protect the circuitry from such disturbances?
Please note that I have played around with an NTC resistor which generally helped. Even so, the resistor tends to get really hot so I'm looking for alternative suggestions. Please see my schematic attached.
Wireless charting unit used:
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005006386722006.html?spm=a2g0o.order_detail.order_detail_item.4.59ea6368vvEc2A&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu


It could be lots of things.  Conducted or radiated EMI, common-mode noise, transients, etc.  Not enough information to pinpoint the cause.
